# How to make Material-UI StepConnector as dots when StepContent is present in the stepper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement the StepConnector as dots in Material-UI stepper. The problem is when the step is active the StepConnector beside the StepContent is not turning into dots. I'm using borderStyle: 'dots' to Override the stepConnector. I am providing the codesandbox link below. I don't understand why the screenshot is not uploading. Please copy and paste the below code in codesandbox to get the UI. Sorry for the trouble. Any help would be really appreciable. Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udiq0.png)

https://codesandbox.io/s/lmb2b?file=/demo.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  makeStyles,
  Theme,
  createStyles,
  withStyles,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepLabel from '@material-ui/core/StepLabel';
import StepContent from '@material-ui/core/StepContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { StepIconProps } from '@material-ui/core/StepIcon';
import StepConnector from '@material-ui/core/StepConnector';

const QontoConnector = withStyles({
  alternativeLabel: {
    top: 10,
    left: 'calc(-50% + 16px)',
    right: 'calc(50% + 16px)',
  },
  active: {
    '& $line': {
      borderColor: '#784af4',
      borderStyle: 'solid',
    },
  },
  completed: {
    '& $line': {
      borderColor: '#784af4',
      borderStyle: 'solid',
    },
  },
  line: {
    borderColor: '#d5d5da',
    borderTopWidth: 3,
    borderRadius: 1,
    borderStyle: 'dashed',
    width: 1,
    borderLeft: -1,
  },
  // lineVertical: {
  //   borderLeftStyle: 'dashed',
  //   borderLeftWidth: 1,
  //   minHeight: 24,
  // },
})(StepConnector);

const useQontoStepIconStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#eaeaf0',
    display: 'flex',
    height: 22,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  active: {
    color: '#784af4',
  },
  circle: {
    width: 8,
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: '50%',
    backgroundColor: 'currentColor',
  },
  completed: {
    color: '#784af4',
    zIndex: 1,
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

function QontoStepIcon(props: StepIconProps) {
  const classes = useQontoStepIconStyles();
  const { active, completed } = props;

  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(classes.root, {
        [classes.active]: active,
      })}
    >
      {completed ? (
        <Check className={classes.completed} />
      ) : (
        <div className={classes.circle} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: '100%',
    },
    button: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    actionsContainer: {
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    resetContainer: {
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    last: {
      borderLeft: '10px',
    },
  })
);

function getSteps() {
  return ['Select campaign settings', 'Create an ad group', 'Create an ad'];
}

function getStepContent(step: number) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return `For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much
          you're willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks
          and geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.`;
    case 1:
      return 'An ad group contains one or more ads which target a shared set of keywords.';
    case 2:
      return `Try out different ad text to see what brings in the most customers,
          and learn how to enhance your ads using features like ad extensions.
          If you run into any problems with your ads, find out how to tell if
          they're running and how to resolve approval issues.`;
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

export default function VerticalLinearStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const steps = getSteps();

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper
        activeStep={activeStep}
        connector={<QontoConnector />}
        orientation='vertical'
      >
        {steps.map((label, index) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel>
              {label}
              <br />
            </StepLabel>
            <StepContent
              classes={{
                last: classes.last,
              }}
            >
              <Typography>{getStepContent(index)}</Typography>
              <div className={classes.actionsContainer}>
                <div>
                  <Button
                    disabled={activeStep === 0}
                    onClick={handleBack}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    Back
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    variant='contained'
                    color='primary'
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </StepContent>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
      {activeStep === steps.length && (
        <Paper square elevation={0} className={classes.resetContainer}>
          <Typography>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
          <Button onClick={handleReset} className={classes.button}>
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Paper>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4do5f

Comment: Thanks @MoshFeu for your help. Now I can get dots to StepConnector.

Comment: Happy to help :)